# How does the demapping/demultiplexing of transport channels to logical channels work?

Tags: telecommunication, networking

I am trying to model WCDMA MAC, but I cannot figure out how to demultiplex HS-DSCH unto DCCH, DTCH.
Also, since I am using E-DCH/HS-DSCH transport channel scheme, how does the data of DCCH  and DTCH mapped to E-DCH on transmitter side would be demapped on the receiver side?
The respective MAC headers do not seem to provide a clue to tell just by looking at the message which part belongs to DTCH and which part belongs to DCCH.

Comment: What is the meaning of all these abbreviations?

Comment: HS-DSCH: High Speed Downlink Shared Channel, E-DCH: Evolved Dedicated Channel, DTCH- Dedicated Traffic Channel, DCCH- Dedicated Control Channel. Though, I think if you have worked on cellular networks, these terms should be clear already.

Comment: It is not good practice to use acronyms because you can not always assume that other people know what you are talking about. It is always better to write the abbreviation out when using them for the first time.